# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el problema que encuentro al relacionar mi página web con la base de datos con el servlet?

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, servlets

**En mi página web aparece el siguiente error cuando inicia sesión el usuario en la página y mete los valores que se encentran en la base de datos:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Les pido ayuda ya que no consigo encontrar donde se encuentra el error dentro de mi código. A continuación les adjunto el código del servlet y el documento xml si necesitan alguna otra página de código no duden en pedírmela** 
**El codigo del servlet:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/login"})
public class login extends HttpServlet {

    private DataSource fuenteDatos = null;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig conf)throws ServletException {
        super.init(conf);
        Context ctx;
        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext();
            fuenteDatos = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/stablesoftware");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String usuario = request.getParameter("user");
        String password = request.getParameter("pass");
        try {
            Connection con = null;
            synchronized (fuenteDatos) {
                try {
                    con = fuenteDatos.getConnection();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                }
            }
            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select * from administradores where Usuario=? and Password=?");
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from administradores where Usuario='" + usuario + "'and Password='" + password + "'");
            if (rs.next()) {
                HttpSession sesion=request.getSession();
                sesion.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
                response.sendRedirect("gestionPrivada.html");
            } else {
                response.sendRedirect("InicioSesion.html");
            }
            /*PreparedStatement pt = con.prepareStatement("select * from usuarios where Usuario=? and Password=?");
            ResultSet rst = pt.executeQuery("select * from usuarios where Usuario='"+usuario+"'and Password='"+password+"'");
            if (rs.next()) {
                response.sendRedirect("index.html");
            }else{
                response.sendRedirect("InicioSesion.html");
            }
            rst.close();
            pt.close();*/
            rs.close();
            st.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

**El siguiente es el codigo del documento xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<webapp>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/stablesoftware</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</webapp>
```

**Y estos son algunos de los errores que aparecen en la consola del netbeans:**

```
at login.doPost(login.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:1)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: intentaste con cerrar y después volver abrir el netbeans porque hay veces que el apache se cae.

Comment: Si eso lo intente varias veces pero sigue apareciendo el mismo error al iniciar sesión.

Comment: Puedes añadir tu archivo server.xml del tomcat?, por el error parece que no tienes configurado el datasource en el servidor

Comment: Tengo dos xml uno de ellos es el que tengo adjuntado. ¿Deseas que te adjunte el otro?